# Mysql - How To Count I'ds that are in ALL days to the fullest

Tags: mysql, sql, date, count, distinct

this query:

```
SELECT date_format(At,'%d %M %Y') as At,
COUNT(ID) as ids 
FROM `purchases`
WHERE At >= '2013-12-08 00:00:00' AND At <= '2013-12-09 23:59:59' 
GROUP BY date_format(At,'%D%M%Y')
```

is not good! the answer should be number (for a period)/ this numbers ids. represent the only ID's who have been in my store for all days and even 5 times in a day.

### this is purchases table

```
column1:At                     
colunm2:ID

 - '2013-09-23 11:00:14',   2:34299989
 - '2013-09-23 11:00:51',   1:100004003444031
 - '2013-09-23 11:01:02',   1:100001273059371
 - '2013-09-23 11:01:02',   1:100001476045767
 - '2013-09-23 11:01:11',   1:1081392435
 - '2013-09-23 11:01:17',   1:100001436850024
 - '2013-09-23 11:01:30',   1:100000663028305
 - '2013-09-23 11:01:38',   1:100003991975009
```

sorry about this table show, i couldn't do it better.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Could you please explain what information you are trying to retrieve, and what are the fields in your database, so we can help you?

Comment: You have a name collision between your table column `At` and your aliased result column `At`.  Whilst in both the `WHERE` and `GROUP BY` clauses MySQL will use the table column in preference to the aliased result column, it would be better to be more explicit by avoiding the name collision - e.g. name the result column `AtDate`.  You may also find MySQL's [`DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) function more convenient than `DATE_FORMAT()` in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

The number of `ID`s that made at least one purchase on each day within the range:

```
SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM (
  SELECT   ID
  FROM     purchases
  WHERE    At >= '2013-12-08' AND At < '2013-12-10' 
  GROUP BY ID
  HAVING   COUNT(DISTINCT DATE(At)) = DATEDIFF('2013-12-10','2013-12-08')
) t
```

The number of `ID`s that made at least 5 purchases on at least one day within the range:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ID) FROM (
  SELECT   ID, DATE(At)
  FROM     purchases
  WHERE    At >= '2013-12-08' AND At < '2013-12-10' 
  GROUP BY ID, DATE(At)
  HAVING   COUNT(*) >= 5
) t
```

(Remove `DISTINCT` from this last query if you are instead after the number times that an `ID` made at least 5 purchases on a single day within the range—i.e. count the same `ID` multiple times if it made at least 5 purchases on each of multiple days).

Comment: A huge thank you, this query is so important, and probably a lot of people need it. It is not clear how no function for it. Goat again many thanks! (Typed double-WHERE WHERE But this simple fix)